# create email from variables R

Tags: r

I'm looking for some help to create an email from multiple name variables in a data frame.  Was wondering if there was quick way to do this with a regex?  Please note that the id will need to be included.  For example, `if id == 1, return an email address is the following format: tim.c.smith@email.com.`  Any help someone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Starting
id = c(1,2)
firstnm = c("tim", "mary") 
midnm = c("chris","sally") 
lastnm = c("smith","jane") 
email = c("","") 
st_df = data.frame(id,firstnm,midnm,lastnm,email)


#Ending
id = c(1,2)
firstnm = c("tim", "mary") 
midnm = c("chris","sally") 
lastnm = c("smith","jane") 
email = c("tim.c.smith@email.com","mary.jane@email.com") 
end_df = data.frame(id,firstnm,midnm,lastnm,email)
```

Comment: Explain why Tim's middle name becomes a character, but Mary's middle name disappears entirely.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen.  The short answer to your question is that some groups ids will have an email format that doesn't use the middle name in the email address, despite the fact that it's published in the data frame.

Comment: Then you need to provide logic if you want to be able to handle such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an `ifelse`

```
st_df$email <- with(st_df, ifelse(id==1, paste0(firstnm, ".", 
      substr(midnm, 1, 1),".", lastnm, "@email.com"),
       paste0(firstnm, ".", lastnm, "@email.com")) )
st_df$email
#[1] "tim.c.smith@email.com" "mary.jane@email.com"
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  WHy you are repeating my comment when I posted the answer first

Comment: We didn't post the same answer, no worries.